# Is there a way to create a command prompt shortcut open as administrator and start in another drive and folder on that server?

Tags: cmd.exe, shortcuts, prompt

I would like to create a cmd.exe shortcut that will open as administrator.  I have already done this.  The default place it opens is on the C:\Windows\system32.  I want it to open on E:\\bin instead.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the shortcut, select Properties, and set the the value of the "Start in"
field to `E:\bin`.

Comment: I tried that and it does not work.

Comment: I tried before answering and it worked on Windows 10 1909.

Comment: Try right-click on `cmd.exe` and select "Send to" the Desktop, then modify this shortcut.